# How to pass variable to React Native's Alert.alert button's onPress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass an object/variable to Alert.alert() function's button **onPress**. Unfortunately I get "undefiend" as result. Here is my code example;

```
console.log("HERE ITEM SHOWS THE CORRECT VALUES", item);

Alert.alert(
    "Warning",
    "Test message",
    [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
            style: "cancel"
        },
        {
            text: "Start",
            onPress: () => { 
                    console.log("-----> HERE I CANNOT GET THE VALUES FOR ITEM", item);
            }
        }
    ]
    

);
```

How can I pass the values? Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:
https://snack.expo.dev/@gavindmello97/moody-raspberries

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {
    var tempVarForTest = "StackOverflow"
    Alert.alert(
      "Warning",
      "Test message",
      [
          {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
              style: "cancel"
          },
          {
              text: "Start",
              onPress: () => { 
                      alert("-----> HERE I CANNOT GET THE VALUES FOR ITEM "+ tempVarForTest);
              }
          }
      ]
      

  );
}}>
    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
      Click me to open alertBox
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

I have used the same code as in your question. Do check if I missed anything. Since it reads the variable, it can also read an object, text, etc.